# Spark Driver running on Kubernetes hung with too old resource version message

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-submit, google-spark-operator

I am running a Spark driver on Kubernetes and it keeps failing with the error

```
 WARN ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Kubernetes client has been closed (this is expected if the application is shutting down.)

io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.WatcherException: too old resource version: 447057600 (447129816)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.AbstractWatchManager.onStatus(AbstractWatchManager.java:395)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.AbstractWatchManager.onMessage(AbstractWatchManager.java:363)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatcherWebSocketListener.onMessage(WatcherWebSocketListener.java:52)
```

These are the versions I am using

```
Base Spark version  3.5.0

Hadoop version - 3.3.4

Spark operator version -  v1beta2-1.3.8-3.1.1
```

The driver runs for a bit, throws the above message and goes into a szombie mode. I have gone through the spark logs, node description, pod statuses/description and all of them check out. I have also tried all solutions posted on Stack overflow and github before and none of them appear to work.

Anyone stuck on this message or fixed it before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this shed any light on it? https://github.com/kubeflow/spark-operator/issues/1498

Comment: I've tried all the changes suggested and none seem to work. I have upgraded my Kubernetes client, spark operator being used is 3.1.1 and Server version is 1.27.10 which all relatively newer than the versions listed in the thread above.